# Backing up wp7.5 SQL Server CE database to the cloud

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I have been using a SQL Server CE database for my application and now I want to implement a feature to backup this database to the cloud. I have the online storage set in place so I just need to find the best way of backing up.

My question is what methods/techniques are available for backing up a SQL Server CE `.sdf` file? I know I can just upload the entire `.sdf` file but as this database grows it will not only take longer and longer but will eat into the user's monthly data allowance of their mobile plan.

Answer (score 2):

To preserve data integrity, you must back up the entire database file. If you can live without that, you could serialize some of the tables as zipped JSON content, to make the uploaad package as small as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will look into serializing of tables.